# Python asyncio task list progress logging

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I need to process a massive amount of data rows and it only makes sense to do this asynchronously.

I need to see list processing status, i.e. `Done processing 1/3`, but when I increment the counter, it always stays at 1. This makes sense since I send the counter into the function. I needed to do this because without it, I would get:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'processed' referenced before assignment
```

**Using Python 3.8**

Any help would be appreciated!

Here's a link to test: https://ideone.com/gRjrf2

I've abstracted my code below:

```
    import os, logging
    import asyncio
     
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s', datefmt='%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S')
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
     
    items = [{"name": "A"}, {"name": "B"}, {"name": "C"}]
     
    processed = 0
     
    async def increment(item):
        count = item.get('count', 0)
        count += 1
        return count
     
    async def get_and_update(item, processed):
        item['count'] = await increment(item)
        # Show progress now, but how?
        processed += 1
        logger.info(f"You can't see me {processed}")
     
    async def run():
        logger.info(f"Processing {len(items)} items...")
        await asyncio.gather(*[
            asyncio.create_task(
                get_and_update(item, processed)
            ) for item in items
        ])
     
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(run())
```

The output I get is:

```
28-Aug-20 11:19:22 INFO     [prog.py:23] Processing 3 items...
28-Aug-20 11:19:22 INFO     [prog.py:20] You can't see me 1
28-Aug-20 11:19:22 INFO     [prog.py:20] You can't see me 1
28-Aug-20 11:19:22 INFO     [prog.py:20] You can't see me 1
```

Comment: What have you found challenging about logging?

Comment: @larsks I've added a link that shows my problem

Comment: Please include the code you're asking about -- and any errors -- **in the question**. I've taken a brief look at your link and I don't see any errors related to logging, but I do see an error that you haven't mentioned here in this question.

Comment: Updated my post

Comment: The advantage of ``asyncio`` (and similar) is for high-latency, I/O bound tasks. This use case has none of that. Consider to use ``multiprocessing`` instead.

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is? What is your expected output? Are you aware that ``processed`` is *local* to ``get_and_update``, and thus always ``0 + 1``, i.e. ``1``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, I am actually doing an HTTP request per row and then writing details from the response into my db, so I would say it is relevant. Just didn't want to add more details that required in regards to the logging issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic problem is that by declaring `processed` as a parameter to `get_and_update`, you're shadowing the global `processed` variable. You need to drop the parameter and then declare `processed` as global within that function, like this:

```
import os, logging
import asyncio
 
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s', datefmt='%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
 
items = [{"name": "A"}, {"name": "B"}, {"name": "C"}]
 
processed = 0
 
async def increment(item):
    count = item.get('count', 0)
    count += 1
    return count
 
async def get_and_update(item):
    global processed

    item['count'] = await increment(item)
    # Show progress now, but how?
    processed += 1
    logger.info(f"You can't see me {processed}")
 
async def run():
    logger.info(f"Processing {len(items)} items...")
    await asyncio.gather(*[
        asyncio.create_task(
            get_and_update(item)
        ) for item in items
    ])
 
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(run())
```

The output of the above is:

```
28-Aug-20 08:15:00 INFO     [asynctest.py:25] Processing 3 items...
28-Aug-20 08:15:00 INFO     [asynctest.py:22] You can't see me 1
28-Aug-20 08:15:00 INFO     [asynctest.py:22] You can't see me 2
28-Aug-20 08:15:00 INFO     [asynctest.py:22] You can't see me 3
```